# Whats wrong with my "while" statement

Tags: c#, validation, date

```
int monthentered = 0;
int dayentered = 0;
int year = 0000;
int [] month = new int [12];
int [] day = new int [31];
bool leap = false;

for (int x = 0; x <= 11; x++)
{
    month[x] = x+1;
}

for (int x = 0; x <= 30; x++)
{
    day[x] = x+1;
}
Console.WriteLine("Please enter a year...");
year = (Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine()));
Console.WriteLine("{0}", year);

Console.WriteLine("Please enter a month...");
monthentered = (Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine()));

Console.WriteLine("Please enter a day...");
dayentered = (Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine()));

while (monthentered == 01 || 03 || 05 || 07 || 08 || 10 || 12)
{
    while (dayentered == 31)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There are only 30 days in this month please re-enter your day...");
        dayentered = (Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine()));
    }
}

while (monthentered == 02)
{
    while (dayentered > 28)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There are only 28 days in this month please re-enter your day...");
        dayentered = (Convert.ToInt16(Console.ReadLine()));
    }
}

Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}/{2}", dayentered, monthentered, year);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Is there anything wrong with line `while (monthentered == 01 || 03 || 05 || 07 || 08 || 10 || 12)`? I getting an error that I don't understand. `"Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'"`

Please help.

Comment: That's not how you write such an if. I assume you're trying the equivalent of `if (montheentered == 01) or (monthentered == 02) or ...)`?

Answer (score 3):

```
while(monthentered == 01 || monthentered == 03 || monthentered == 05 || monthentered == 07 || monthentered == 08 || monthentered == 10 || monthentered == 12)
```

Every operation between || and && have to render to a boolean value (i.e. a complete test) since every operation is independently calculated

Answer (score 2):

Now it is something like `while(bool || int || int)`, I guess that you want something like this:

```
while (monthentered == 1 || monthentered == 3 || monthentered == 5 /*|| ...*/)
```

You need to check value of variable every time so it will be `while(bool || bool || bool)` etc

You can also create collection of valid months and check wheter entered number is in it.

Answer (score 2):

> Operator '||' cannot be applied to operands of type 'bool' and 'int'

You can't use `||` on numbers - each part you are using `||` with should evaluate to a `bool`.

The conditional should look like:

```
while (monthentered == 01 || 
       monthentered == 03 || 
       monthentered == 05 || 
       monthentered == 07 || 
       monthentered == 08 || 
       monthentered == 10 || 
       monthentered == 12)
```

Though a more readable option would be:

```
var validMonths = new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12 };

while(validMonths.Contains(monthentered))
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
while (monthentered  == 01 ||monthentered  == 03 || monthentered  ==05 || monthentered  ==07 || monthentered  ==08 || monthentered  ==10 || monthentered  ==12)
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot compare an `int` with a `bool` with [`||` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6373h346%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). `monthentered == 01` is a `bool`(true/false) and the rest are `ints`.

So change the while to:

```
int[] allAllowedMonths = new[]{ 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12 };
while (allAllowedMonths.Contains( monthentered ))
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

C# while only accept true/false expressions!

```
while (monthentered == 01 || monthentered ==03 || monthentered ==05 || monthentered ==07 || monthentered ==08 || monthentered ==10 || monthentered ==12)
```

Answer (score 0):

it should be

```
while (monthentered == 01 || 
       monthentered == 03 || 
       monthentered == 05 || 
       monthentered == 07 || 
       monthentered == 08 || 
       monthentered == 10 || 
       monthentered == 12)

 {  
   //code here
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Direct answer that leads to code that *compiles* but won't *work*: you need to use

```
(monthentered == 01 || monthentered == 03 || monthentered == 05 ||
 monthentered == 07 || monthentered == 08 || monthentered == 10 ||
 monthentered == 12)
```

Further issues:

- your code allows 32+ days in most months.
- your `while` loops on months will never terminate, as you never change the value of the month. Use an `if` statement instead.

Extra hint: you can use [`DateTime.DaysInMonth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx) to get the maximum number to allow for each month and year, rather than manually checking the month number. This will also accommodate leap years.

Comment: Does it? I've glinced over it. Can you point out where I've made this error please?

Comment: For example, if your month is 1, you only say "There are only 30 days in this month " if `(dayentered == 31)` rather than if `(dayentered >= 31)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'm new to the programming course and I'm struggling to get to grips. Tank you for help.

Comment: not only while loops on months... you'll have to change all your "while" clauses with "if" ones.

Comment: No, the dayentered while loop is fine because dayentered changes in the loop body.

Answer (score 0):

It's tedious syntax but you would need to write the while statement as:

`while (monthentered == 01 || monthentered == 02 || monthentered == 3` ...etc

Your statement will first  evaluate the boolean condition `monthentered == 01` and then try to logically or the result with the other numbers which are ints hence the error.

However I'd take a look at what you're trying to do and see if a while loop is really what you want here.